# how can I display the child object values(children) with the main object?

Tags: javascript

```
let state=["Karnataka","Andharapradesh","Tamilnadu"];
console.log(state);
document.write("<br>"+state);
for (i=0;i<=state.length-1;i++){
document.write(state[i]);
}
```

// -- question part--

```
 let person = {
    name: prompt("Your name"),
    age: prompt("age?"),
    spouse:prompt("spouse name"),
    address: prompt("enter your address"),
    children :{
        child1: "kamal",
        child2: prompt("name of the child"),
             }
}
console.log(person);
for(let values in person){
    document.write( "<br>" + values + ":" + person[values]);
}
```

**// output
Karnataka,Andharapradesh,Tamilnadu
name:jashdk
age:khsald
spouse:kashdl
address:lksadlka
children:[object Object]**

// it will display only main object values and the child value as children:[object Object]

Comment: You have to loop through the children object to display them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a tree search like this:

```
const treeSearch = (obj) => {
for(let values in obj) {
    document.write("<br>" + values + ":" + obj[values]);
}
```

}

Then you can implement that by checking if the person object contains a object as one of it's keys values.

```
// Full Code
let person = {
    name: prompt("Your name"),
    age: prompt("age?"),
    spouse:prompt("spouse name"),
    address: prompt("enter your address"),
    children :{
        child1: "kamal",
        child2: prompt("name of the child"),
    }
}

const treeSearch = (obj) => {
    for(let values in obj) {
        document.write("<br>" + values + ":" + obj[values]);
    }
}

for(let values in person){
    if(typeof person[values] == "object") {
        treeSearch(person[values]);
    } else {
        document.write( "<br>" + values + ":" + person[values]);
    }
}
```

That should work.